# How call a wizard to add new Item Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wizard, vsix, itemtemplate

I have a project template that is generated through a wizard.
Now i want to add a new item template through the same wizard.
How can i invoke the wizard at the moment that i add the new item template.

Example:

[image: Add to Project Template][Add to Project Template]

[image: Wizard/Form][Wizard/Form]

[image: Add the new Item Template][Add the new Item Template]

[image: Show the wizard Template][Show the wizard Template]

[image: show the new Item/class][show the new Item/class]

Item Template Code:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>class1.cs</DefaultName>
    <Name>Myproject class1</Name>
    <Description>Myproject Class</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>Myprojectclass1.png</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System.Linq</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System.Threading.Tasks</Assembly>
      </Reference>
    </References>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">class1.cs</ProjectItem>
    <CustomParameters>  
        <CustomParameter Name="$username$" Value="$safeitemrootname$"/> 
        <CustomParameter Name="$rootnamespace$" Value="$safeitemrootname$"/>
        <CustomParameter Name="$registeredorganization$" Value="$safeitemrootname$"/>
    </CustomParameters>  
  </TemplateContent>
    <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>MyProjectWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=f7a1fcb8d457e160</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>MyProjectWizard.WizardImplementation</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found the solution, there is no other way to call the template item without being key.snk.

Because when I call an itemtemplate I have to implement my item I chose the project created and the only way to do that is by key.snk.

If they have a different form please respond to this question, I want to know if there are more ways to call the Item template.